# Prevent a selected <option>-tag from being overwritten by .html()

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP file that fetches rows of car brands from a database, echoes these as `"<option value=\"$brand\">" . $brand . "</option>";` and puts them inside pre-written `<select>`tags.

My issue is that the first item that appears in the select box is not passing its value onwards.

The value of the select box is changed by this event

```
$('select[name=model]').on('change', function() {
  selectedModel = $("#select-model").val()
});
```

The `<option>`-tags are generated by this loop in `brands.php`:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $brand = $row['brand'];
  echo "<option value=\"$brand\">" . $brand . "</option>";
}
```

The brands are fetched by this function:

```
function fetchBrands() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script/rent/brands.php",
    data: {dateFrom: selectedDateFrom, 
           dateTo: selectedDateTo, 
           destination: selectedDestination},

    success: function(data) {
        $("#select-brand").html(data);
      }
  });
}
```

Because the data is posted to `#select-brand`with `.html()` I can't set a default value for the select box because it gets overwritten. Appending the options will result in duplicates etc. as `fetchBrands()` is dependent on a previous set of radio buttons and select boxes.

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code that is doing this?

Comment: Then use the attribute `selected="selected" on the audi `<option> tag

Comment: Another way of achieving the same result would be to add a first row with something like "Please select a value" that way the user is force to change the `select`'s value.

Comment: @Technoh yeah I tried doing that at first. However, the `<option>` tags constantly change because they are dependent on the result of a previous set of radio buttons. I could use .append(), but that will just fill up the select box with duplicates etc. The problem is that I use `.html()` to post the `<option>` tags, so it overwrites what's inside the select box.

Comment: @robert Then you are missing crucial information on your question. Show how you are adding the options and what the problem is.

Comment: @R2D2 I added some extra code now. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: @robert I still don't understand the question :( You should always try to post a question that has all that is needed to reproduce a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve For example, you don't need AJAX, give it hardcoded data, and reproduce the problem, that makes it much easier for others to understand what is going on and to be able to tinker with it.

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm sorry. I wasn't sure how to approach the problem myself, so I tried to limit the amount of code to include. I've solved it, though, thanks to Huw Jones' help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd now suggest is that in your success function, add some code that gets the first element in the select tag, updates the `selectedBrand`, and then triggers the code that's attached to the change event.
If you refactored your code so that you added a reference to the handler code, this would make it easier.

```
$('select[name=model]').on('change', someFunction());

function someFunction(){
    selectedModel = $("#select-model").val()
}

function fetchBrands() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script/rent/brands.php",
    data: {dateFrom: selectedDateFrom, 
           dateTo: selectedDateTo, 
           destination: selectedDestination},

    success: function(data) {
        $("#select-brand").html(data);
        $("#select-brand").val($("#select-brand option:first").val());
        someFunction();
      }
  });
}
```

### Before extra information was added:

To have an element of a `<select>...</select>` automatically selected on page render, you need to add the attribute `selected="selected"` to the `<option />` you want to be selected.

Alternatively, add a hook for document load that sets the selected brand.

Or, have the first option as something like this:

```
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose a Brand</option>
```

Comment: This exactly how I expected. I after the `$("#select-brand").html(data);` I added another line `$("#select-brand").append('<option value="" selected>Select an option</option>');` which is always selected first when a new set of `<option>` are fetched. It appears at the bottom of the select. Having it at the top would be more desirable, but it's working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @robert use prepend to make your added selected option  come first http://api.jquery.com/prepend/